# C# LINQ ObjectParameter turns STP output to SQL Data type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I've been looking for answer and couldn't find it, something really weird is going on.

i have SQL Stored procedure that returns output parameter as a smallint.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [STP_NAME] 
@Out_Error_Level    Smallint OUTPUT
SELECT @Out_Error_Level = 0
```

pretty simple and works perfectly when i execute thru SQL Management studio.

now what weird is that when i execute thru C# Link i get 'Bigint'. C# code is also simple:

```
DS_RAS_CD_APPEntities2 db = new DS_RAS_CD_APPEntities2();
ObjectParameter outputError = new ObjectParameter("Out_Error_Level", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
var updateProcessesList2 = db.STP_NAME(outputError);
Console.WriteLine(outputError.Value);
```

the result is : BigInt.
[image]

now when i change output in sql to different number i get some sort of data types, for example: 1 returns Binary, 2 returns Bit, 3 returns Char, 10 returns Nchar.

it ends when i set @Out_Error_Level = 35, then the result is 35.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the constructor for ObjectParameter you will see there are two overloads:

```
ObjectParameter(String name, Object value)
ObjectParameter(String name, Type type)
```

If you look at what you are providing as the second parameter then it is not a Type so it must be using the first overload.

If we then look at what it says about that second overload:

> value
>   Type: System.Object
>   The initial value (and inherently, the type) of the parameter.

So as you can see it is taking the value you have passed (`SqlDbType.SmallInt`) as a default value and is using this to work out the type that the object should be - in this case of course the enum `SqlDbType`. So every number you are passing back is being translated into its enum equivalent. Once you provide numbers that don't exist in the enum it just returns the number itself.

What you likely want to be doing is

```
new ObjectParameter("Out_Error_Level", typeof(Int16));
```

I use `Int16` because that is the equivalent for the database SmallInt. You could equally use the more common `Int32` and I'd expect it to work fine.

Source of information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectparameter.objectparameter(v=vs.113).aspx

To conclude if you are getting wrong results then I would advise always looking at the documentation you are provided for the objects and methods you are using and make sure that you aren't making any wrong assumptions about how it works...